# Handle enter button in change_form Django

Tags: python, django, button

I'm new with Django and python. I have a problem. Is there a way, after click enter button to be redirected to the same change_form page without being passed to change_list page by Django? This is the UI that I mean:

[image]

(enter button in under all fieldset)
Hope you can understand what i mean and give me some responses. Thank you :).

Comment: What does your enter button do, and how is it different to the Save button provided as default?

Comment: yes, it's different. I want my enter button can pass instances from "Kode Produk" fieldset to tabularinline. But i dont know how.

Comment: Have any link that is the same or almost the same with my question ? And also with the answers or hints. thank you :).

Comment: if your question is answered.please mark the suitable answer

Comment: oh, sorry im new to know it. Does it by clicking the checklist mark of every answer ? :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the submit_line.html template

I've changed:

```
{% if show_save %}<input name="_save" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{% endif %}
```

to:

```
{% if show_save %}<input name="_continue" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{% endif %}
```

which will cause the default save-button to act as the save-and-continue-button.

this [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894493/django-override-admin-change-form-html-template-display-associated-model-in-te) or the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) may help you to change the submit_line-template correctly

complete "submit_line.html":

```
{% load i18n %}
<div class="submit-row">
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_continue" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link %}<p class="deletelink-box"><a href="delete/" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>{% endif %}
{% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{%endif%}
{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" {{ onclick_attrib }} />{% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: but, you mean that the enter button will act like "Save and Continue Editing" button, right ? Or i dont really get what you mean ? And then, does it cause refresh page ? because i need no refresh page. Thank you :).

Comment: if you hit enter your browser trigger the default submit-button of that particular html form.in this case it is the "save"-button.by changing the name-attribute of that button it will act like the save-and-continue button

Comment: Oke, that's match of what i thought. But, what i mean is that button will then directly save all my fieldset i've just fill in ? If yes, where will it be saved ? changelist ? Really big thanks for you :D.

Comment: everything will be saved just fine :) django is interpreting the value of that name-attribute.if it is "_save" it will redirect you to the change_list-view if it is "_continue" it will redirect you to the same view as before.

Comment: Ohh That's really a hit answer for me ! Thank you very much :).

Comment: you're welcome.if you like you can remove the save-and-continue-button from the template, because it is redundant.

Comment: Oh that's really what i want before im stuck with this kinda stuff :D. But how can i remove the save-and-continue-button from the template ? By extending submit_line.html or what ? thank you again :D.

Comment: Wow, haha, big thanks really. I think i've got what i want. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the django admin, there's three buttons:

> - Save and Add New
> - **Save and Continue Editing** ( you need to click this one )
> - Save

If you're talking about your own apps, add a next parameter to your forms catch it in form validation and redirect accordingly

**Edit:**

I see you created a custom button, you can override the save/enter method in your ModelAdmin and redirect to wherever you want. Just add a hidden next input to your form.

**Example:**

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # other stuff
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

your change form template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{request.path}}" />
```

Comment: Sorry, can you give some sample codes or pseudocode so that i can understand clearly. Sorry, im really a newbie :).

Comment: But im using fieldset from model, how can i set them as hidden ? Sorry but i still don't know what you mean of {{request.path}} ? Really sorry and big thanks your kindly responses :).

Answer (score 0):

the enter button, will cause the underlying html-form to be submitted.
this has nothing todo with django or python and is browser specific.

the django change_form has three submit-buttons, the last one will used.

there are multiple ways todo this:

- override hange_form-template and add some jquery to react on the keypress event (enter) and fire the button of choice.
- reorder those buttons

Comment: Oh i see, but is there a way without using jquery ? js maybe ? :S.

Comment: i posted an alternative answer :)