# Can we disply registered model forms side by side in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

In admin.py

```
class Employee_wage_detailsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee_wage_details
    extra = 0

class Employee_masterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    inlines = [Employee_wage_detailsInline]  
    list_display = ('employee_code', 'employee_name','designation','weekly_off_day','gender','payment_type','status') 

admin.site.register(Employee_master,Employee_masterAdmin)
```

Now in the Admin section the entry form are coming one under another. Can we change the looks and make the forms side by side? Or how to modify the html file , to design according to mine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
class Employee_wage_detailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Employee_wage_details
    extra = 0
```

If it doesn't give you what you want, you need to modify `change_form.html`.

[Django Override Admin change_form.html Template - display associated model in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894493/django-override-admin-change-form-html-template-display-associated-model-in-te)

Comment: Thanks @sachitad again, yes your suggestion is fine. But still I think have to Override Admin change_form.html to make proper customization as per my requirement.

Comment: Yes, for the proper and precise look, you have to customize the template! :)